# Where does Magento get its HTML from?

Tags: magento

I've been messing around in Magento because a client uses it but for the life of me I can not understand how Magento is loading pages. Every page is a PHP script that pulls some magical files out of the air and displays them. I've ordered a book on how this works but it wont be here for a while.

What I want to know for now is where the actual HTML that Magento is loading is kept. There must be a folder that holds chunks of HTML that Magento sticks together, yes?

Comment: What I like to do when working with unknown projects is grep the source code for specific pieces of the HTML code. This will usually turn up the template location.

Comment: Welcome to web applications. The content resides in a database and is presented through templates and module blocks which is what generates html. The good old days of static html web pages are fast disappearing, unless you're working with content that doesn't change much.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I'm used to PHP updating web pages, but Ive never used something with so many pieces of code stuck together. Each page is a ridiculous number of scripts stuck together.

Comment: Welcome to the ultimate abstraction machine. Somebody once said that Magento is built by programmers for programmers. EAV is what happens when you normalize each piece of data to its ultimate conclusion. A table for each data type? It's a maze zing... with the emphasis on maze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 main sources (ordered by significance):

- Templates - `app/design/<area>/<package>/<theme>/template/...`. This is the most general source of HTML
- Blocks - `app/code/<pool>/<Namespace>/<Module>/Block/...`. Some of them return direct html or contain rules on composing and wrapping templates, other blocks.
- Library classes - `lib`. They can contain HTML, which is used by Magento.

Occasionally, HTML can be present in another locations as well (e.g. several models or controllers) - but it is a rare/exceptional practice.

Comment: Beautiful! Finally found these things!

Answer (score 0):

Magento's templates are located in the `app/design/frontend` folder — anything with a `phtml` ending is template that contains mixed PHP and HTML.  There's *many* templates used to render a Magento page.  You can get an idea of the templates involved by look at the Block tab of the [Commerce Bug](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/) demo site (self link, Commerce Bug is a Magento debugging extension I created and sell, but the demo site is free) — although chances are your client's system is using a custom theme which will have it's templates in different locations.

Comment: Lego blocks with holes that are filled by other lego blocks is one way of describing Magento's template system.